# how to use \algsetup in latex environment

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am using the "algorithmic" environment and want to use \algsetup. But getting an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}

\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}

  \scriptsize

\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

The above is producing

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmicindent already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.51 \newlength{\algorithmicindent}

?
```

EDIT (prasenjit) the follwoing errors are produced

Command \algorithmicrequire already defined. ...nd{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}

Command \algorithmicensure already defined. ...mand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Ensure:}}

Command \algorithmiccomment already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{{#1}}

Command \algorithmicend already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}

Command \algorithmicif already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}

Command \algorithmicthen already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}

Command \algorithmicelse already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{else}}

Command \algorithmicfor already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{for}}

Command \algorithmicforall already defined. ...mand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for all}}

Command \algorithmicdo already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{do}}

Command \algorithmicwhile already defined. ...command{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{while}}

Command \algorithmicloop already defined. \newcommand{\algorithmicloop}{\textbf{loop}}

Command \algorithmicrepeat already defined. ...mmand{\algorithmicrepeat}{\textbf{repeat}}

Command \algorithmicuntil already defined. ...command{\algorithmicuntil}{\textbf{until}}

Command \algorithmic already defined. {\end{list}}

Undefined control sequence \algsetup

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                     \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                     \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                     \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \If

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \If

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \If

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \Else

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \Else

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \Else

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                               \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                               \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                               \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                          \State

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \EndIf

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \EndIf

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \EndIf

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{algorithmic}

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

Underfull \hbox (badness 2088) in paragraph

Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Comment: Please make your example into a complete document that generates the error, `\usepackage` has to be in the preamble, `\begin{algorithmic}` has to be in the document, so if your document is exactly as above that may be the source of error...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Are you asking me to put all the \usepackage inside \begin{document}. I tried that. But, the error remains.

Comment: No exactly the opposite, but you need to make your example into a document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` all `\usepackage` before `\begin{document}` all environments after `\begin{document}` That is _always_ the case, not just for `algorithmicx`

Comment: I did it for you this time, note it is now a complete document that people can test and it includes the exact error message.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did not get. My code is same as it looks like after your modification. Still it is giving error. What is the solution? It works properly without the \algsetup.

Comment: I may look up `algorithmicx` later but there are people on site more familiar with the package, I was just editing the question to make the question have a reasonable chance of an answer. In the form you posted the original document you would have an error with any package and any environment, so unlikely to get any answers specific to the actual problem.

Comment: algpsuedocode is part of algorithmicx bundle, but algorithmic package is part of the separate algorithms bundle, are you sure they are compatible?

Comment: in TeX only the first error is really of any use, later errors (if you do not stop at the first) are typically spurious as a result of whatever action Tex took to recover. Also you can use `{}` to format the display from the log as a verbatim section.